# JLabel disappears after a setText()

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlabel, settext

I'm setting up a mock program in an MVC fashion with Swing. I'm having troubles calling setText on a JLabel from an external Thread. I know Swing has its own threading model (setText is thread-safe though), so I've also tried forcing the setText call to be carried out by the EDT via SwingUtilities functions, with no results.

This is what the classes look like - *I've omitted the irrelevant chunks, suppose they have references to each other and the GUI's layout is properly set up*:

```
public class View extends JFrame
{
    private final JLabel label = new JLabel("idle");
    private final JButton button = new JButton("press me");

    public View(final Controller controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;

        button.addListener(e -> controller.input());
    }

    public void refresh(final boolean value)
    {
        label.setText(value ? "YEP" : "NOPE");
    }
}

public class Controller
{
    private final ExecutorService service =
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void input()
    {
        service.submit((Runnable) () ->
        {
            try
            {
                view.refresh(true);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(final InterruptedException exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                view.refresh(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Expected behavior:

1. Button is pressed
2. `input()` is called on `controller`
3. A new thread is created, which first sets `label`'s text to "YEP"
4. The newly created thread simulates some delay with `Thread.sleep()`
5. It awakens and sets `label`'s text to "NOPE"

What I get is that after the call at point 3 the label disappears, **but is drawn again at 5**, showing the text "NOPE".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Beware, Swing is not thread safe. You might consider using a Swing `Timer` instead of an `ExecutorService`

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Please show more code. I've added a main method, added the label and the button to the frame and on my computer with my code it works (i.e. the label does not disappear but shows "YEP"/"NOPE")